# Golang import packages

Tags: go, importerror

I have some problem with Golang and include package. I have that scructure

```
src/
├── hello_world
│   ├── hello.go
│   └── math
│       └── add.go
```

**hello.go** file contains this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    math "hello_world/math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    x := math.add(6, 5)
}
```

and **add.go**

```
package math

func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

and when I do `go run hello go` I see:

```
evgen@laptop:~/go/src/hello_world$ go run hello.go 
# command-line-arguments
./hello.go:10: cannot refer to unexported name math.add
./hello.go:10: undefined: "hello_world/math".add
```

**GOPATH**:

```
evgen@laptop:~/go/src/hello_world$ echo $GOPATH
/home/evgen/go
```

How fix it? Thanks you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outside of a package only the exported identifiers can be reached and referred to, that is identifiers that start with an uppercase letter.

So the easiest fix is to export your `math.add()` function by changing its name to `Add()` in `math.go`:

```
func Add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

And, of course, when you refer to it from the `main.go`:

```
x := math.Add(6, 5)
```

And as a side note, note that when importing your `hello_world/math` package you don't have to specify a new name to refer to its exported identifiers: by default it will be the last part of its import path, so this is equivalent to your imports:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "hello_world/math"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Capitalize the function within your package that you want other functions to read:

```
func Add(x, y int) int {
      return x + y
}
```

then call it in **hello.go** like this:

```
x := math.Add(6, 5)
```

Keeping them lower case does have its purpose, particularly if you want to protect it from inadvertent use outside the package.

Answer (score 0):

And when calling Add in your main function, dont use this

```
x := math.Add(6 + 5)
```

Instead use this

```
x := math.Add(6, 5)
```

Comment: You can edit answers from other users instead to post a new answer correcting another one

Answer (score 0):

Functions, variables , anything coming from  a different package have to start with a capital letter to make it visible for when importing into the main package.

example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "other/out"

func main(){

fmt.Println(out.X)

// hello

}
```

```
package other

var X string = "hi"
```